# Даны числа a, b, c, d, при этом 0≤c<d. Выведите в порядке возрастания все числа от a до b, которые дают остаток c при делении на d

Tags: python, алгоритм, циклы

**Нельзя использовать if и операторы сравнения (< и т.д.), должен быть только один цикл for.**

Пример входных данных:
1 4 1 2,
Выходные данные:
1 3

Пример входных данных:
1 5 0 4,
Выходные данные:
4

Моя попытка

```
a = int(input())  # 1
b = int(input())  # 5
c = int(input())  # 0
d = int(input())  # 4

for i in range(a + ((a % d != c) * (d-c)), b, d):
    print(i, end=' ')
```

Т.е. я к первому числу последовательности прибавлял некоторое число (пробовал d - c), умноженное на логическое выражение a % d != c (т.е. я проверял, подходит ли первое число последовательности
и если оно подходило, то ничего не прибавлял, если не подходило то прибавлял), далее просто проходился от a до b  с шагом d

Но такое решение не проходит проверку уже на втором тесте (1 5 0 4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В вопросе не приведено точное условие: входят ли сами `a` и `b` в диапазон? Я посчитал, что входят.

Округляем `a - c` вверх до числа. кратного `d`  и добавляем `c`, чтобы остаток по модулю `d` был равен этому значению.

```
a,b,c,d = 1,5,0,4
for i in range(c + (a - c + d - 1) // d * d, b + 1, d):
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавил разветвление для 2 вариантов, если с = 0 и если с != 0, теперь вроде бы работает

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
c = int(input())
d = int(input())

for i in range(a + (a % d != c) * ((c == 0) * (d-c-1) + (c != 0) * (d - c)), b, d):
    print(i, end=' ')
```

Comment: Это точно то, что надо сделать в задании? Мягко говоря, слабо читаемый код

Comment: Вы не учли, что b тоже может быть нужным числом. Питон будет идти до b-1

Answer (score 0):

Сначала найдем число больше либо равное а, которое дает нужный остаток. Далее вывести числа с шагом.

```
a=a+(d-a%d+c) %d
for i in range(a, b+1,d):
    print(i)
```

Объяснение магической формулы. Сколько не хватает до d? d-a%d. Добавим нужный остаток. Если получится d то a это первое нужное число.

Answer (score -2):

```
a, b, c, d = int(input()), int(input()), int(input()), int(input())
a = ((a + d - c - 1) // d) * d + c
for i in range(a, b + 1, d):
    print(i)
```

работает отвечаю

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @Степан Шустов А вы другие ответы читаете?